# Using NavLink with styled component in React Router Dom 6 is adding function to class

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, styled-components

I am trying to use `styled-components` with `NavLink` from `react-router-dom@6`.

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { NavLink as BaseNavLink } from "react-router-dom";

export const StyledNavLink = styled(BaseNavLink)``;
```

and then use above `StyledNavLink` like below

```
<Styled.StyledNavLink
  className={({ isActive }:any) => (isActive ? "active" : "")}
  to="/contact"
>
  Contact
</Styled.StyledNavLink>
```

But in the UI when the link is generated, its class looks like below,

```
<a aria-current="page" class="sc-hLseeU befAUD ({
 isActive
}) => isActive ? &quot;active&quot; : &quot;&quot; active" href="#/contact">
  Contact
</a>
```

Please check the class attribute of the `<a>` tag. It has all the function definition in addition to the active class.

This never used to happen with `react-router-dom@5`, but it's happening after migrating to `react-router-dom@6`.

Demo link: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-cori-fmy9zk

Answer (score 2):

The `styled-component` `styled` utility overrides the `className` prop. It's stringifying any passed `className` function and injecting it into the DOM. To get around this you'll need to implement some custom logic to apply the `NavLink` `className` logic on another prop that won't be overwritten and then merge it along with the regular string `className` prop that `styled` injects.

`NavLink.styled.ts` is renamed to `NavLink.styled.tsx` so TSX is validly used in the file.

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { NavLink as BaseNavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import type { NavLinkProps as BaseNavLinkProps } from "react-router-dom";

interface NavLinkProps extends BaseNavLinkProps {
  customClassName?:
    | string
    | ((props: {
        isActive: boolean;
        isPending?: boolean;
      }) => string | undefined);
}

const NavLink = ({ customClassName, className, ...props }: NavLinkProps) => {
  const getCustomClassName = (props) => {
    switch (typeof customClassName) {
      case "function":
        return customClassName(props);

      case "string":
        return customClassName;

      default:
        return undefined;
    }
  };

  return (
    <BaseNavLink
      className={(props) =>
        [
          getCustomClassName(props), // NavLink "prop"
          className                  // styled-component "prop"
        ]
          .filter(Boolean)
          .join(" ")
      }
      {...props}
    />
  );
};

export const StyledNavLink = styled(NavLink)<NavLinkProps>``;
```

The UI using the `StyledNavLink` component will use an `customClassName` prop instead of `className` and pass the same function or string value.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <nav>
        <StyledNavLink
          to="/home"
          customClassName={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "current" : "")}
        >
          Home
        </StyledNavLink>
        <StyledNavLink
          to="/about"
          customClassName={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "current" : "")}
        >
          About Us
        </StyledNavLink>
        <StyledNavLink
          customClassName="current" // <-- always applied
          to="/contact"
        >
          Contact
        </StyledNavLink>
      </nav>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<ContactUs />} />
      </Routes>
    </HashRouter>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit using-navlink-with-styled-component-in-react-router-dom-6-is-adding-function-to]

[image]

Comment: @ajm Sorry, realized that I didn't implement the *exact* same behavior as the `NavLink`... I was conditionally applying the string value when the link was active when in reality it's only when using the function does the active state come into play. I've updated answer and sandbox.

Answer (score -1):

The main reason why the styled NavLink is adding the function definition to the class attribute is because of the way that styled-components works. styled-components uses a technique called **tagged template literals** to create the CSS styles for a component which means that the CSS styles are actually JavaScript code, and the function definition is part of that code.

In React Router Dom v6, the NavLink component now uses a prop called activeClassName to specify the class that is applied to the NavLink when it is active. This means that the function definition is no longer needed in the class attribute, because the activeClassName prop will take care of it.

***Here's the code which I have changed***

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { NavLink as BaseNavLink } from "react-router-dom";

export const StyledNavLink = styled(BaseNavLink)`
  
`;

const NavLink = ({ to, activeClassName }) => (
  <Styled.StyledNavLink
    className={activeClassName}
    to={to}
  >
    ...
  </Styled.StyledNavLink>
);

export default NavLink;
```

I think this will remove the function definition from the class attribute, and the NavLink will be styled correctly.